# Implementing post('updateOne') hook middleware with Mongoose(MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to calculate the average value of the `ratings` for a Product per Document that is being rated. Instead of calculating the average rating of the Product every time when we need the value. I calculate it every time someone rates it. To accomplish this task I am implementing a `post(‘updateOne’)` hook middleware. Though not sure I can accomplish this by implementing this hook. Let me know if I am going into the wrong direction. Here is the error I am getting `avgRating error from post updateOne hookTypeError: Cannot read property 'aggregate' of undefined`.

file - **Product.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      text: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 32,
    },
    quantity: Number,
    ratings: [
      {
        star: Number,
        postedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const avgRating = async function () {
  try {
    const stats = await this.aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          avgRating: { $avg: '$ratings.star' },
          nRatings: { $size: '$ratings' },
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log('stats: ', stats);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`avgRating error from post updateOne hook${err}`);
  }
};

// Call avgRating after updateOne
ParentSchema.post(
  'updateOne',
  { document: true, query: false },
  async function () {
    await avgRating();
  }
);

export default mongoose.models.Product ||
  mongoose.model('Product', ParentSchema);
```

file - **productServices.js**

```
import Product from './Product.js';

const updateRating = async (existingRatingObject, star) => {
  const query = {
    ratings: { $elemMatch: existingRatingObject },
  };
  const update = { $set: { 'ratings.$.star': star } };
  const option = { new: true };
  try {
    const doc = new Product();
    const ratingUpdated = await doc.updateOne(query, update, option);
    return ratingUpdated;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('product model updateRating error: ', error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **avgRating** function does not have access to the mongoose document under `this`. That is why you are getting the error, *Cannot read property 'aggregate' of undefined*, because `this` (the document) which you want to modify does not exists in the function.

You need to use an instance method available under mongoose. With instance method, you can call `this` to reference the document.

Check out:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-d2a7aa593c57/#instace-methods

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods